# How to convert seconds duration to iso-8601 by specify unit using moment?

Tags: javascript, iso8601

I'm using moment to convert seconds duration to ISO-8601, but sometimes it will cause confusion;
Like 14 days = 14*24*60*60 seconds;
It could transfer to P2W or P14D;
Is it possible to specify the unit of ISO-8601 by using moment?
Like by specify "Week", it will return P2W here.

Comment: Have you tried to research this?